# Is it mandatory to upgrade backup ILL connection when MPLS circuit is upgraded?

Tags: mpls

In our office we have both MPLS and ILL connection. We recently upgraded our office MPLS bandwidth connection from 20 Mbps to 50 Mbps. Currently 20 Mbps ILL connection we have. Is it mandatory to upgrade ILL connection too? If Yes, what are the reasons to have ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check your own requirements. There is no general law on how to do these things. As it is, your question is too broad and soliciting opinions which is off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it mandatory to upgrade ILL connection too

Simple answer is "**NO**". In management perspective, you cannot increase bandwidth as per your own idea. you should plan capacity and then you can increase capacity based on requirement.

In this situation also, you can increase bandwidth if you have requirement. Otherwise it will be money wasting.